# Need to mount a drive before samba kicks in at boot. How to?

Tags: samba

How do I make sure that a hard drive is mounted to a certain location before samba kicks in?  I'd like to use the samba to share out the hard drive.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like the basic task of mounting drives in `etc/fstab`, which is fairly simple.  This is where your other partitions are mounted, such as swap, /home if separate, etc.

This file is a simple text file that you edit using something like gedit or vim, such as `sudo gedit /etc/fstab`.

By the way, you don't really mount drives, you mount partitions (actually filesystems, but thinking of it as partitions is usually fine).  Do you know how to use the `mount` command?

Answer (score 0):

That should happen automatically. If it doesn't, just run `sudo restart smbd` to restart the samba daemon (after the drive is mounted).

Comment: would like for it to kick in on boot just in case I cant ssh in